# how to use multiple ref in my react input

Tags: reactjs

hello guys pls i have a challenge in my react app, i am trying to enable multiple choice login where a user can either use his mail or even hi username to login. i got it working from my server using postman but when i try it on my frontend it doesnt allow me to use multiple refs on it, i am only allowed to use either the username or email.
Here is my code

```
function Login() {
  const password = useRef();
  const email = useRef();
  const username = useRef();

  const { isFetching, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      loginCall(
        {
          username: username.current.value,
          email: email.current.value,
          password: password.current.value,
        },
        dispatch
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="log__bg">
        <div className="login">
          <div className="loginWrapper">
            <div className="loginLeft">
              <span className="loginDesc">Welcome Back</span>
              <ToastContainer />
            </div>

            <div className="loginRight">
              <form className="loginBox" onSubmit={handleClick} >
                <input
                  placeholder="Email, phone, or username"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  className="loginInput"
                  ref={username}
                />
                <input
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  required
                  minLength="6"
                  className="loginInput"
                  ref={password}
                />
                <button
                  className="loginButton"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={isFetching}
                >
                  {isFetching ? (
                    <CircularProgress color="white" size="20px" />
                  ) : (
                    "Log In"
                  )}
                </button>

                <Link id="auth_route" to="/register">
                  <button className="loginRegButton">
                    {isFetching ? (
                      <CircularProgress color="white" size="20px" />
                    ) : (
                      "Create a New Account"
                    )}
                  </button>
                </Link>

                <div className="forgot__password">
                  <Link className="forgot__password__btn" to="/forgot-password">
                    Forgot Password?
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need 2 refs ? user will provide username or email in the same input field. Use just one ref than you can have a logic or regex in your backend to detect if the provided value is an email or a username:

```js
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let username = null
    let email = null
    const emailRegex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/
    const inputValue = username.current.value

    if(inputValue.match(emailRegex)){
      email = inputValue
    } else {
      username = inputValue
    }
    
    try {
      loginCall(
        {
          username: username,
          email: email,
          password: password.current.value,
        },
        dispatch
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  };
```

With this if the user provided an email, username will be sent as null to the server and vice versa. Then you can check on the server if you get an email or a username.

UPDATE:
You can also just use a state and don't use ref at all:

```js
  const [usernameValue, setUsernameValue]=React.useState("")
  const [passwordValue, setPasswordValue]=React.useState("")

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let username = null
    let email = null
    const emailRegex = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/

    if(usernameValue.match(emailRegex)){
      email = inputValue
    } else {
      username = inputValue
    }
    
    try {
      loginCall(
        {
          username: username,
          email: email,
          password: passwordValue,
        },
        dispatch
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  };


  return (
    ...
            <form className="loginBox" onSubmit={handleClick} >
                <input
                  placeholder="Email, phone, or username"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  className="loginInput"
                  value={usernameValue}
                  onChange={e=>setUsernameValue(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  required
                  minLength="6"
                  className="loginInput"
                  value={passwordValue}
                  onChange={e=>setPasswordValue(e.target.value)}
                />
    ...
    ...

  )
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried this it didnt work, already from my backend the logic is working correctly.... now with this your sample what should be inside the ref for the input ..like,                 ref={}

Comment: You should use just the username ref. `ref={username}` or not a ref at all. You can just use a state. I'll update my answer to show you how to use a state instead

Comment: thanks, i tried the both and nothing worked, now for the state i got an error instead saying Cannot read properties of null (reading 'current')

Comment: hello, thanks once again, i have solved it and even understand much better all you said. However, i have commented an answer to my post, you can check out what i did. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PatersonCode, the best way would be to use `React.useState` and just one variable to store your input value.

You didn't mention what error you're getting, but here's an example that I hope might help you in some way:

https://codesandbox.io/s/choose-login-method-example-xgpfue?file=/src/Login.js

Comment: when i try passing the ref on the input, am allowed to pass only one of them that is either email or username, and i will still have to comment one (either email or login depending the one am currently using ) in my loginCall function because it will throw undefined when i leeave it that way

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone that helped, i have solved it and the problem was that i needed to use one ref (email or username) and also that same ref in my loginCall. here is the updated code.

```
function Login() {
  const password = useRef();
  const username = useRef();

  const { isFetching, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      loginCall(
        {
          username: username.current.value,
          email: username.current.value,
          password: password.current.value,
        },
        dispatch
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="log__bg">
        <div className="login">
          <div className="loginWrapper">
            <div className="loginLeft">
              <span className="loginDesc">Welcome Back</span>
              <ToastContainer />
            </div>

            <div className="loginRight">
              <form className="loginBox" onSubmit={handleClick} >
                <input
                  placeholder="Email, phone, or username"
                  type="text"
                  required
                  className="loginInput"
                  ref={username}
                />
                <input
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  required
                  minLength="6"
                  className="loginInput"
                  ref={password}
                />
                <button
                  className="loginButton"
                  type="submit"
                  disabled={isFetching}
                >
                  {isFetching ? (
                    <CircularProgress color="white" size="20px" />
                  ) : (
                    "Log In"
                  )}
                </button>

                <Link id="auth_route" to="/register">
                  <button className="loginRegButton">
                    {isFetching ? (
                      <CircularProgress color="white" size="20px" />
                    ) : (
                      "Create a New Account"
                    )}
                  </button>
                </Link>

                <div className="forgot__password">
                  <Link className="forgot__password__btn" to="/forgot-password">
                    Forgot Password?
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```